# android download manager download to external removable sd card

Tags: android

I tried to use android download manager to download file.

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/myfile", "abc.txt");
enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);
```

So the file will be downloaded to `/storage/sdcard/myfile/abc.txt`.

However, for external removal sd card, the path is `/storage/sdcard1/`.

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir
```

defaults is `/storage/sdcard/`.

How can I set the download path to `/storage/sdcard1/myfile/abc.txt`?

Comment: just specify manually the path

Comment: how?? setDestinationInExternalPublicDir confines the path to sdcard0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setDestination` instead. THis is an example. Change this `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to your hardcoded path.

```
File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator);
Uri path = Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.fromFile(root), "this_is_downloaded_file.png");
request.setDestinationUri(path);
```